# Curl request to Php Curl Request

Tags: php, api, curl

I need a help rewriting this request to php curl:

```
curl -d '{"text":"Hello,
#param#.","port":[2,3],"param":[{"number":"123456","text_param
":["John"],"user_id":1},{"number":"123478",
"text_param":["Sam"],"user_id":2}]}’ –H "Content-Type:
application/json" http://gateway_ip/api/send_sms
```

So far i didnt have any success. here is what i tried:

```
$url = "http://url/api/send_sms";

$params = array(
    'auth' => 'user:pass',
    'port' => 7,
    'text' => utf8_encode('Hello, world!')
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using http_build_query when you're wanting to send JSON?

Comment: @JonStirling Well I guess that is the part I copied from somewhere, can you elaborate?

Comment: Where are curl_exec() and also check curl_error() for errors. See here at this example: http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-error.php#refsect1-function.curl-error-examples

Comment: you are looking for: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

$json = <<<JSON
{"text":"Hello,
#param#.","port":[2,3],"param":[{"number":"123456","text_param
":["John"],"user_id":1},{"number":"123478",
"text_param":["Sam"],"user_id":2}]}
JSON;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://gateway_ip/api/send_sms");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Build $json var by your own, but create a valid json with **json_encode** function